# Inductor datasheet: What is "Typ. (MHz)"?

Tags: inductor

In an [inductor's datasheet](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/pm5022_series-268734.pdf):

[image: typ inductor]

Usually "Typ." stands for typical.
But I have a hard time understanding, for example the first row (1uH unductor), since its SRF frequency is 7.96MHz, what could the Typical 100MHz frequency used for/ referred to?

I would expect the typical frequency to mean the "maximum frequency to operate the inductor to, so you wont surpass the SRF", in the case of 1uH here, I would except the typical frequency to be less than 7.96MHz, something close to 6MHz.

I observe the Typ. frequency gets reduced as the inductance increases, but I cannot understand how Typ. frequency value helps me, the engineer in the use/design/implementation of the inductor.

Comment: My guess is, its a bad-written datasheet. If one looks as [this](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/srr1280-1391363.pdf) datasheet, it doesn't mention "Typ. MHz", it says "SRF, Test" frequencies.

Comment: Haha, they swapped the column labels. Go figure.

Comment: Contacting Bourns to have them correct the datasheet would probably be a good thing here.

Comment: @user4574 Yeah I contacted them using their online contact form.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They have got the columns mixed up.

If you look on their [website](https://www.bourns.com/search?indexCatalogue=psindex&searchQuery=PM5022*), for the 1 μH part, it has an SRF of 100 MHz and 7.96 MHz is the test frequency for measuring Q-factor: -

[image]